# Test file structure in groovy(Spock)

Tags: testing, groovy, spock, filetree

How to test created and expected file tree in groovy(Spock)?
Right now I'm using Set where I specify paths which I expect to get and collecting actual paths in this way:

```
Set<String> getCreatedFilePaths(String root) {
    Set<String> createFilePaths = new HashSet<>()
    new File(root).eachFileRecurse {
        createFilePaths << it.absolutePath
    }
    return createFilePaths
}
```

But the readability of the test isn't so good.
Is it possible in groovy to write expected paths as a tree, and after that compare with actual

For example, expected:

```
region:
     usa:
       new_york.json
       california.json
  europe:
       spain.json
       italy.json
```

And actual will be converted to this kind of tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it with the built-in recursive methods. There certainly are powerful ones, but this is standard recursion code you can use:

```
def path = new File("/Users/me/Downloads")

def printTree(File file, Integer level) {
    println "   " * level + "${file.name}:"
    file.eachFile {
        println "   " * (level + 1) + it.name
    }
    file.eachDir {
        printTree(it, level + 1)
    }
}

printTree(path, 1)
```

That prints the format you describe

Comment: I think the OP wants to parse that structure, not create it.

Comment: I want to compare my actual file tree with expected in a readable way. Actually, the idea is nice, only need this method to return String, and in this case, I can compare my Strings.

Comment: [modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710225/test-file-structure-in-groovyspock/#answer-51726693) your answer and it looks nice and simple for me

Answer (score 1):

You can either build your own parser or use Groovy's built-in JSON parser:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import groovy.json.JsonParserType
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import spock.lang.Specification

class FileRecursionTest extends Specification {
  def jsonDirectoryTree = """{
      com : {
        na : {
          tests : [
            MyBaseIT.groovy
          ]
        },
        twg : {
          sample : {
            model : [
              PrimeNumberCalculatorSpec.groovy
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      de : {
        scrum_master : {
          stackoverflow : [
            AllowedPasswordsTest.groovy,
            CarTest.groovy,
            FileRecursionTest.groovy,
            {
              foo : [
                LoginIT.groovy,
                LoginModule.groovy,
                LoginPage.groovy,
                LoginValidationPage.groovy,
                User.groovy
              ]
            },
            LuceneTest.groovy
          ],
          testing : [
            GebTestHelper.groovy,
            RestartBrowserIT.groovy,
            SampleGebIT.groovy
          ]
        }
      }
    }"""

  def "Parse directory tree JSON representation"() {
    given:
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper(type: JsonParserType.LAX)
    def rootDirectory = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonDirectoryTree)

    expect:
    rootDirectory.de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.contains("CarTest.groovy")
    rootDirectory.com.twg.sample.model.contains("PrimeNumberCalculatorSpec.groovy")

    when:
    def fileList = objectGraphToFileList("src/test/groovy", rootDirectory)
    fileList.each { println it }

    then:
    fileList.size() == 14
    fileList.contains("src/test/groovy/de/scrum_master/stackoverflow/CarTest.groovy")
    fileList.contains("src/test/groovy/com/twg/sample/model/PrimeNumberCalculatorSpec.groovy")
  }

  List<File> objectGraphToFileList(String directoryPath, Object directoryContent) {
    List<File> files = []
    directoryContent.each {
      switch (it) {
        case String:
          files << directoryPath + "/" + it
          break
        case Map:
          files += objectGraphToFileList(directoryPath, it)
          break
        case Map.Entry:
          files += objectGraphToFileList(directoryPath + "/" + (it as Map.Entry).key, (it as Map.Entry).value)
          break
        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected directory content value $it")
      }
    }
    files
  }

}
```

Please note:

- I used `new JsonSlurper(type: JsonParserType.LAX)` in order to avoid having to quote each single String in the JSON structure. If your file names contain spaces or other special characters, you will have to use something like `"my file name"`, though.
- In `rootDirectory.de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.contains("CarTest.groovy")` you can see how you can nicely interact with the parsed JSON object graph in `.property` syntax. You might like it or not, need it or not.
- Recursive method `objectGraphToFileList` converts the parsed object graph to a list of files (if you prefer a set, change it, but `File.eachFileRecurse(..)` should not yield any duplicates, so the set is not needed.
- If you do not like the parentheses etc. in the JSON, you can still build your own parser.
- You might want to add another utility method to create a JSON string like the given one from a validated directory structure, so you have less work when writing similar tests.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea, but as for me, it looks a little bit overloaded for reading.

Comment: I understand. The upside is that JSON is a standard format. But you can also easily brew your own coffee. 

Answer (score 0):

Modified [Bavo Bruylandt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710225/test-file-structure-in-groovyspock#answer-51715838) answer to collect file tree paths, and sort it to not care about the order of files.

```
def "check directory structure"() {
    expect:
    String created = getCreatedFilePaths(new File("/tmp/region"))
    String expected = new File("expected.txt").text

    created == expected
}

private String getCreatedFilePaths(File root) {
        List paths = new ArrayList()
        printTree(root, 0, paths)
        return paths.join("\n")
    }

private void printTree(File file, Integer level, List paths) {
        paths << ("\t" * level + "${file.name}:")
        file.listFiles().sort{it.name}.each {
            if (it.isFile()) {
                paths << ("\t" * (level + 1) + it.name)
            }
            if (it.isDirectory()) {
                collectFileTree(it, level + 1, paths)
            }
        }
    }
```

And expected files put in the expected.txt file with indent(\t) in this way:

```
region:
    usa:
        new_york.json
        california.json
    europe:
        spain.json
        italy.json
```